# IronPython vs Python vs C# performance of for loops

Tags: python, c#, performance, ironpython

I am relatively new to Python and IronPython. I was suprised about the performance (should I say slowness) of a relatively simple code I wrote:

```
matrix_column_count=1000
matrix_row_count=2000
matrix=[[random.uniform(0,100) for i in range(matrix_column_count)] for j in range(matrix_row_count)]
```

Running this on IronPython 2.7.10 takes (with some  small variations) about  1 sec!
Running on Python 3.8.6 takes 0.55 sec
Running something similar in C# takes 0.03 sec !

Are these numbers "normal" for Python development vs C# development or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, these are numbers are correct. As I cannot comment (not enough stack overflow points), so I will copy paste another similar answer here from stack overflow

> The answer is simply that Python deals with objects for everything and
> that it doesn't have JIT by default. So rather than being very
> efficient by modifying a few bytes on the stack and optimizing the hot
> parts of the code (i.e., the iteration) – Python chugs along with rich
> objects representing numbers and no on-the-fly optimizations.
>
> If you tried this in a variant of Python that has JIT (for example,
> PyPy) I guarantee you that you'll see a massive difference.
>
> A general tip is to avoid standard Python for very computationally
> expensive operations (especially if this is for a backend serving
> requests from multiple clients). Java, C#, JavaScript, etc. with JIT
> are incomparably more efficient.

Check the detailed answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29904752/13993546

Also, you might want to check detailed comparison of Python benchmarks vs other programming languages, so here are the links, which might be useful for you:

https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/fastest/python.html

https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/fastest/csharp.html

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer!